# Solution to a non-exact ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE I want to solve is 
$$ \cos(x) dx + (4ye^{-y} + \sin(x)) dy = 0 $$
with the initial value $ y( \pi )= 0 $

The ODE is not exact because

$P(x,y)= \cos(x) $

$\frac{\partial P(x,y) }{ \partial y} =0 $

and

$Q(x,y)= 4ye^{-y} + \sin(x) $

$\frac{\partial Q(x,y) }{ \partial x} =\cos(x) $

So I need an integrable factor $M$:
 $$ \frac{ \partial}{ \partial y}[ M( \cos(x) )]= \frac{ \partial }{ \partial x} [M(4ye^{-y}+ \sin(x)] $$

$$\leftrightarrow M \cos(x) = \frac{ \partial M}{ \partial y} \cos(x) - \frac{ \partial M }{ \partial x} (4ye^{-y}+ \sin(x)$$

I choose  $ \frac{ \partial M }{ \partial x}=0 $
So it comes to

$M \cos(x) = \frac{ \partial M }{ \partial y} \cos(x) \leftrightarrow M'=M \rightarrow M(y)= e^y + c$

So it comes to the exact ODE
$$ \cos(x) e^y dx +( 4e^ye^{-y}+ \sin(x) e^y) dy =0 $$

Integration leads to

$$ \int \cos(x) e^y dx= e^y \sin(x) + c \\ \int 4+ \sin(x)e^y dy = \sin(x)e^y+4y+c $$

So I can choose $ F(x,y)= \sin(x)e^y+4y $
Is this right so far?
How do I solve it with the initial values?

Comment: You should have $2y^2$ not $4y$

Answer (score 1):

*As you said we should multiply by $e^{y}$
To get $$e^{y}(\cos(x)dx+\sin(x)dy) \ +  \ 4ydy = 0$$
now just integrate to get* $$e^{y}\sin(x)+2y^2=C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos(x) dx + (4ye^{-y} + \sin(x)) dy = 0$$
$$d\sin x + \sin(x)dy+ 4ye^{-y}dy  = 0$$
Multiply by $e^y$:
$$(e^yd\sin x + \sin(x)de^y)+4ydy = 0$$
$$(de^y\sin x) + 2dy^2  = 0$$
Integration gives:
$$e^y \sin x +2y^2=C$$
You made a little mistake for $y$. You wrote:
$$ \int 4+ \sin(x)e^y dy = \sin(x)e^y+4y+c$$
It should be:
$$\int \color{red}{4y}+ \sin(x)e^y dy = \sin(x)e^y+\color{red}{2y^2}+c$$

Comment: ah yes, thank you so much ! At this point I am confused at how to solve the initial value problem with $y( \pi ) = 0 $. How do I set it right?

Comment: @constant94 it gives $e^0 \sin \pi +2*0^2=C \implies \sin \pi =C \implies C=0$